# How to hide arguments from URL with a custom mapper TYPO3 9.5?

Tags: php, typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x

Previously my URL without implementing a custom mapper looked like this:
**https:\mydomain.com?tx_myextension%5Baction%5D=boat-action&tx_myextension%5BboatId%5D=boat-id&tx_myextension%5BboatName%5D=boat-name&tx_myextension%5Bcontroller%5D=boat-controller&cHash=hash**

After the implementation of a custom URL mapper by extending the custom aspects I’ve reached this solution: 
**https:\mydomain.com/boat-name/boat-id**

What I am trying to achieve is to hide the **boat-id** from the URL, the ID is not stored in a table and it is required from the pages to load the datas.

*Html that generates the link*

```
<f:link.action  
    class="call-to-action horizontal" 
    action=“boat-action” 
    controller=“boat-controller”
    arguments="{
        boatId: '{boat.id}',
        boatName: '{boat.urlName}'
    }" 
    pageUid="218"
>
```

*config.yaml*

```
routeEnhancers:
    BoatName:
      type: Extbase
      limitToPages:
        - 218
      extension: myextension
      plugin: Singleboat
      routes:
        - routePath: '/{boatName}/{boatId}'
          _controller: Boat::boat-controller
      aspects:
        boatId:
          type: BoatNameMapper
        boatName:
          type: BoatNameMapper
```

*custom mapper class*

```
class BoatNameMapper implements StaticMappableAspectInterface
{
    use SiteLanguageAwareTrait;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function generate(string $value): ?string
    {
        return $value !== false ? (string)$value : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function resolve(string $value): ?string
    {
        return isset($value) ? (string)$value : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your boat-Id in the URL, don't put it in. (config.yaml)

and especially: make your controller independent of the boat-Id. Otherwise you need it in the URL.

---

maybe an acceptable solution is another coding of boat-name and boat-Id.

what about: `- routePath: '/{boatName}-{boatId}`